# Cannot scale sitecore with solr search

Tags: xml, solr, content-management-system, sitecore, sitecore7

I am using Solr 4.3.0 and referring [this](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore7/70/sitecore_search_scaling%20guide_sc7-a4.pdf) document where I am generating the schema.xml by clicking **Generate the Solr Schema.xml file** in the control panel but I am not able to figure out what exactly should I do the two schema.xml files and where exactly am I supposed to place it. I could not proceed until I find a way. I am stuck at page 31 on the PDF.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Open the location of Solr core configuration, e.g. `C:\solr-4.3.0\example\solr\itembuckets\conf`
2. Copy `schema.xml` file to `original-schema.xml`
3. Login to `Sitecore Desktop`
4. Open `Control Panel` -> `Indexing` application
5. Select `Generate the Solr Schema.xml file`
6. For `Source File` select **original-schema.xml** from the point 2.
7. For `Target File` select **schema.xml** from point 2.
8. Click `Generate >`

Sitecore will use the `original-schema.xml` file as a base and will override `schema.xml` Solr configuration with the configuration containing required changes.

Comment: Quick note: If you are dealing with a Solr version above 4.8 there is now a KB article that may be useful : https://kb.sitecore.net/articles/227897

Comment: I get an error in my CMS after I replace **Inherits="Sitecore.Web.Application"** with **Inherits="Sitecore.ContentSearch.SolrProvider.CastleWindsorIntegration.WindsorApplication"** for specifying IOC Container

Comment: What error? Do you have `Castle.Core.dll`, `Castle.Windsor.dll` and `Castle.Facilities.SolrNetIntegration.dll` dlls in your bin directory? You may want to start new question.